# Как корректно отправить cookie?

Tags: jquery, javascript, cookie

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, снова прошу вашей помощи. Собственно вопрос звучит "Как корректно отправить cookie?". Задача такова: До отправки cookie выполнить проверку (проверка на существование самой cookie или на ее значение). Т.е. по сути данная проверка нужна, чтобы условие ELSE отработало по первому запуска страницы.

У меня же получается так, что cookie уже сразу отправляются клиенту, и смысла от условия нету. Мот я что не правильно делаю?

Имеем скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Проверка
    if ($.cookie("visit") == 1) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        alert("Печеньки пока, что нету!");
    }

    // ПОСЛЕ!!! проверки отправляем cookie
    var cookieValue = 1;
        $.cookie("visit", cookieValue);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше *добавление куки* добавить в условие, т.к.

```
$.cookie("visit") != 1
```

сработает только один раз: запишет куку и больше не будет вызываться. Как-никак, а экономия.

Т.е.:

```
// Проверка
if ($.cookie("visit") == 1) {
    return false;   
} else {
    $.cookie("visit", 1);
}
```

Comment: Я почему-то не могу уже прокомментировать свой ответ, поэтому отвечу тут: где это @archi_sova "потом сказал об этом"? Вам тоже без разницы, отправлять или устанавливать? :)

Comment: @Zhukov Roman да я повнимательней перечитал комментарии, переосмыслил содержание :-) Но суть одна, понять можно было, что автор хотел)

Comment: @lampa, поэтому я пытался объяснить правильную терминологию, чтобы в будущем не возникало непонятных вопросов. Кроме того, сначала вообще сложилось ощущение, что автор не в курсе, как функционируют кукисы, иначе бы такой путаницы не возникло. Что там кода-то? if, else, между ними по функции? И на этом возник затык?..

Comment: @Zhukov Roman ну да, это правильно.

Comment: @lampa Чувак ты мега-крут! С удовольствием посидел бы с тобой за кружкой пивца :) Ты не только мне помогаешь, но и многим здесь на этом форуме! Честно говоря я почему-то ждал твоего ответа :)

Comment: @lampa А еще вопрос! Как принудительно удалить куки при закрытии вкладки? Или как установить жизнб кукисов например 15 минут?

Comment: @archi_sova у некоторых браузеров есть обработчик события на закрытие вкладки. Туда просто помещаете: $.removeCookie('the_cookie'); По остальным вопросам: как удалить куку, как поставить патч куке, как задать срок жизни - читаем документацию: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie :-)

Comment: Пасибо! :)

Answer (score 3):

Куда вы хотите отправить cookie? Cookie отправляется клиентом (в данном случае - браузер) вместе с запросом страницы браузером. Остановить этот процесс вы не можете (вернее можете, но только на следующий запрос - предварительно удалив эту cookie).

Хоть бы на Wiki зашли:

> Ку́ки (слово не склоняется; от англ. cookie — печенье) — небольшой фрагмент данных, отправленный веб-сервером и хранимый на компьютере пользователя, который веб-клиент (обычно веб-браузер) **каждый раз пересылает веб-серверу в HTTP-запросе при попытке открыть страницу соответствующего сайта**.

Comment: Вы про [ЭТО][1] слышали что-нить?

А отправить я хочу клиенту! Вы бы советом помогли, а не беседу проводили...
  [1]: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_cookie

Comment: Очередная обертка native-функций? Конечно слышал. Теперь объясните получше слова: "cookie" уже сразу отправляются клиенту. Кто отправляет? Кто клиент?

Ваш код, который вне условия, никуда ничего не отправляет, а УСТАНАВЛИВАЕТ cookie на клиент.

Comment: Хочу выполнять запуск функции, но запуск осуществлять только один раз при первом посещении страницы, страница является шаблоном для всех остальных поскольку меня CMS, получается, что при переходе на другие страницы эта функции снова выполняется, а это делать уже не надо. Вот я решил эту проблему реализовать с помощью отправки cookie.

Comment: О чем вы говорите? Какие native-функции? Это обычный плагин! Устанавливает или отправляет, какая разница?

Comment: Где выполняется запуск функции? На сервере? На клиенте? Еще раз спрашиваю: когда вы говорите, что "отправляете cookie" - вы что имеете в виду?

Comment: Куда плагин отправляет cookie, что за бред вы несёте? Ох...

Comment: Если вы не понимаете разницу между "устанавливает" и "отправляет" — дальнейший разговор не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, Роман! Смотрите! Ситуация такая! 1. Загрузилась страница 2. Поверх этой страницы, появилось сообщение 3. Мы его закрыли 4. Дальше серфим по сайту, и чтобы нам это окно снова не появлялось каждый раз, я добавил реализацию с помощью установленной cookie. Вроде бы понятно выразился!